# AS3 XML, nodeName with attributes comes up blank

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I've tried many different ways of accessing the name of an attribute, but just can't get it working.

The current Function:

```
protected function applyProperties(_axml:XML):void
{
    var list:XMLList = _axml.properties;
    var list2:XMLList = list.attributes();

    for (var i = 0; i < list2.length(); i++) {
        trace(list2[i].nodeName.toString());
    }
}
```

The XML it's referring to:

```
<content type="media">
<target>warning.png</target>
<properties x="20" mouseEnabled="$false"></properties>
</content>
```

I have tried the name, I've tried searching it as an Object, I looked for solutions on stackoverflow.. nothing has worked for me so far. Originally I had the properties node as such:
 fearing that Flash was interpretting incorrectly.

edit: It seems like the XML was interpretted rather than printed out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list2[i] would be an XML object.

XML objects do not have nodeName, thats a XMLNode object.

try

```
list2[i].name().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed this for a project of mine, and this piece of code worked as a charm:

```
for (var u:uint=0; u<myXMLList[i].attributes().length(); u++){
               LevelOne::DataXML.questionset..q[i].@[myXMLList[i].attributes()[u].name().toString()] = myXMLList[i].attributes()[u];
               LevelTwo::DataXML.questionset..q[i].@[myXMLList[i].attributes()[u].name().toString()] = myXMLList[i].attributes()[u];
               LevelThree::DataXML.questionset..q[i].@[myXMLList[i].attributes()[u].name().toString()] = myXMLList[i].attributes()[u];
            }
```

Thanks WORMSS!